# C++ Primer (5th ed.) : Is "16.3 Overloading and Templates" wrong in all its "more specialized" examples?

Tags: c++, templates, type-deduction

Section 16.3 of C++ Primer (5th edition) - Overloading and Templates -, teaches the function matching procedure in the presence of candidate function template(s) instantiations.

Here are the declaration for the function templates used in this section:

```
using std::string;
template <class T> string debug_rep(const T &); /* 1 */
template <class T> string debug_rep(T *);       /* 2 */
// definitions not relevant for the questions
```

#### First example

```
string s("SO");
debug_rep(&s);
```

it is then said that the generated instantiations will thus be:

1. `debug_rep(const string *&)` (with `T` bound to `string *`)
2. `debug_rep(string *)`

*Q1* Is it correct for #1 ? Should not it instantiate `debug_rep(string* const &)` instead?

#### Second example

```
const string *sp = &s;
debug_rep(sp); //string literal type is const char[10]
```

it is then said that the generated instantiations will thus be:

1. `debug_rep(const string *&)` (with `T` bound to `const string *`)
2. `debug_rep(const string *)`

Thus, both instantiated candidate would provide an exact match, selection being made on the more specialized template (-> #2)

*Q2.1* Is it correct for #1 ? Should not it instantiate `debug_rep(const string* const &)`?

*Q2.2* Assuming the instantiated function is the one just above, can we affirm it is not an exact match any more ?

#### Third example

```
debug_rep("SO world!"); //string literal type is const char[10]
```

it is then said that the generated instantiations will thus be:

1. `debug_rep(const T &)` (with `T` bound to `char[10]`)
2. `debug_rep(const string *)`

Thus, both instantiated candidate would provide an exact match, selection being made on the more specialized template (-> #2)

*Q3.1* Is the type deduced for `T` correct in #1 ? Should not it be `const char[10]` instead ?

*Q3.2* Assuming the deduced type for `T` is actually the one just above, can we affirm it is not an exact match any more ?

Comment: Could the user that downvoted the question please detail its reason(s), so I can try to take my question up to the standard ?

Comment: Yeah I think the author dropped the ball a bit on this chapter. I found another error earlier on at the end of 16.2.5 - _As with nontemplate functions, the first version will bind to modifiable rvalues and the
second to lvalues or to const rvalues._ Not true, try passing a non-const lvalue expression to `f` and the first one gets called, not the second (due to reference collapsing).

Answer (score 3):

You're given these declarations:

```
using std::string;
template <class T> string debug_rep(const T &); /* 1 */
template <class T> string debug_rep(T *);       /* 2 */
```

---

In the invocation

```
string s("SO");
debug_rep(&s);
```

the `&s` produces a `string*`, which can only match the `T const&` of (1) when `T` is `string*`.  For the `T*` in (2), there is a match for `T` bound to `string`. So, provided your quoting is correct, the book is wrong about

> ```
> debug_rep(const string *&)
> ```

being a possible instantiation: there is no such.

The instantiation resulting from `T` = `string*` would instead be

```
debug_rep( string* const& )
```

But which instantiation will be called?

As a general rule the simplest match is superior, but I never manage to remember the exact rules, so, I ask Visual C++ (because its `typeid(T).name()` produces readable type names by default):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <typeinfo>
using namespace std;

template< class T >
struct Type {};

template <class T> auto debug_rep( T const& )   // 1
    -> string
{ return string() + "1 --> T = " + typeid(Type<T>).name(); }

template <class T> auto debug_rep( T* )         // 2
    -> string
{ return string() + "2 --> T = " + typeid(Type<T>).name(); }

auto main() -> int
{
    string s( "SO" );
    cout << debug_rep( &s ) << endl;
    cout << "The type 'int const' is shown as " << typeid(Type<int const>).name() << endl;
}
```

And it says:

```
2 --> T = struct Type<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > >
The type 'int const' is shown as struct Type<int const >
```

And so on for your second and third examples: apparently the author got some mixup regarding `const`.

Comment: `typeid` and templates don't get on very well because `typeid` discards possible cv-qualifiers of `T`.

Comment: @black: Right. It doesn't matter in the code above, which is just about showing which template is chosen. But to pick up the outer-`const` information where you want it you can define `template<class T> struct Type{};` and then write e.g. `typeid<Type<T>>.name()`.

Comment: @black: Thinking about it, perhaps it's best to do that also here. Updating answer… Thanks.

Comment: Nice and simple trick to avoid discarding top-level const-qualification with `typeid` ! You would not happen to have one that does not discard the reference when given a reference type ? ; )

Comment: @AdN have a template function which accepts a T&& and tries to instantiate that undefined template class.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: Thanks to **Alf** answer, and its elegant trick to conserve complete information about a type while using `typeid`, I was able to write a program that addresses most of my questions (changing from `std::string` to `int` for output readability.)
The complete code can be edited and run [rextester online IDE](http://rextester.com/DBBQ28669).

Let's define a few classes and methods:

```
template <class> class Type{}; // Allowing to get full type information with typeid
 
template <class T> std::string typeStr()
{ return typeid(Type<T>).name(); }

template <class T> void debug_rep(const T &a) /* 1 */
{
    std::cout << "[1] T type is: "    << typeStr<T>()
              << "\t| arg type is: " << typeStr<decltype(a)>() << std::endl;
}

template <class T> void force_1(const T &a)   /* 1 */
{
    std::cout << "[forced 1] T type is: "    << typeStr<T>()
              << "\t| arg type is: " << typeStr<decltype(a)>() << std::endl;
}

template <class T> void debug_rep(T *a)       /* 2 */
{
    std::cout << "[2] T type is: "    << typeStr<T>()
              << "\t| arg type is: " << typeStr<decltype(a)>() << std::endl;
}
```

### example 1

Running:

```
std::cout << "---First example---" << std::endl;
int i = 41;
debug_rep(&i);
force_1(&i);
```

Displays:

```
---First example---
[2] T type is: class Type<int>  | arg type is: class Type<int *>
[forced 1] T type is: class Type<int *> | arg type is: class Type<int * const &>
```

**Q1**: we can remark that, when we call force_1, instantiating a template corresponding to #1, the argument type is `int * const &`, so the book is not correct, and the instantiated candidate #1 would be

1. `debug_rep(int* const &)`

### example 2

Running:

```
std::cout << "---Second example---" << std::endl;
const int *ip = &i;
debug_rep(ip);
force_1(ip);
```

Displays:

```
---Second example---
[2] T type is: class Type<int const >   | arg type is: class Type<int const *>
[forced 1] T type is: class Type<int const *>   | arg type is: class Type<int const * const &>
```

**Q2.1**: Calling `force_1`, we remark that the argument type will be `int const * const &`, so the book is missing const qualification on the reference. The instantiated candidate will actually be:

1. `debug_rep(const int * const &)`

**Q2.2** The second candidate being `debug_rep(const int *)`, it is an exact match for `ip` (which is a pointer to constant integer). To check if the first candidate has a lower rank, let's write:

```
void debug_rep_plain_b(const int * const &)   /* 1 */
{ std::cout << "[plain 1]" << std::endl;}

void debug_rep_plain_b(const int *)           /* 2 */
{ std::cout << "[plain 2]" << std::endl; }
```

If we try to compile:

```
debug_rep_plain_b(ip)
```

There is a compilation error for ambiguous call: So the answer to Q2.2 is NO, it is still an exact match ! For the templated version, the compiler actually uses the rule regarding the *most specialized template* to resolve the ambiguity.
Even if there is a mistake in the deduced candidate, the book is correct regarding the fact that this example illustrates overload resolution using the most specialized template.

### example 3

Running:

```
std::cout << "---Third example---" << std::endl;
const int ia[3] = {1, 2, 3};
debug_rep(ia);
force_1(ia);
```

Displays:

```
---Third example---
[2] T type is: class Type<int const >   | arg type is: class Type<int const *>
[forced 1] T type is: class Type<int const [3]> | arg type is: class Type<int const (&)[3]>
```

**Q3.1** The type deduced for `T` by CL is array of **const** integer, so the book would be mistaken.

**BUT** the result is inconsistent with GCC or Clang, that would output:

```
---Third example---
[2] T type is:4TypeIKiE | arg type is: 4TypeIPKiE
[forced 1] T type is:4TypeIA3_iE    | arg type is: 4TypeIRA3_KiE
```

The interesting part being:
[forced 1] T type is:4TypeI**A3_i**E
meaning that they deduce `T` as an array of 3 **non**-const integers (because _i, not _Ki), which would agree with the book.

I will have to open another question for this one, I cannot understand the type deduction operated by GCC and Clang...

Comment: The Visual C++ 19 online compiler at http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/ prints `[forced 1] T type is: class Type<int [3]>` for the third example. Probably a bug in earlier versions. -- If we shall disregard the "original answer", then why don't you just remove it?

Comment: Thank you for your comment! It is interesting that the latest version of CL agrees with GCC and Clang: this behavior is probably the expected one as you pointed out. I just need to understand why (I felt deducing an array of `const int` was more intuitive).
I was not sure it was good etiquette to remove an answer completely, but as it introduces noise and no one commented on its content, you are right I will remove it.

Comment: *"I just need to understand why"* An interesting question. As it turns out, this was subject to Defect Report [CWG 1059](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1059) and [CWG 1610](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_active.html#1610). Basically, the const-qualification of the element type is (also) part of the array type. I'll try to find out why it is treated this way. See also [CWG 112](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_defects.html#112)

Comment: @dyp Thank you for the pointers. It seems to me it would be a question on its own, so I asked it as a new one:
http://stackoverflow.com/q/30893036/1027706