# Why does template parameter deduction for T 'skips' the constness of array elements when function parameter is const reference to T?

Tags: c++, arrays, template-argument-deduction

Let's consider those definitions:

```
/*** full type information with typeid ***/
template <class> class Type{};

template <class T> std::string typeStr()
{ return typeid(Type<T>).name(); }

/*** function template for parameter deduction ***/
template <class T> void func(const T &a)
{
    std::cout << "Deduced type for T is: " << typeStr<T>() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "\targument type is: " << typeStr<decltype(a)>() << std::endl;
}
```

### with pointers to const

If the following statements are executed:

```
const int i=5, *ip=&i;
func(ip);
```

The output is:

```
Deduced type for T is: 4TypeI**PKi**E
```

So `T` is actually deduced as a pointer to a constant integer. The fact that the argument is a reference-to-const does not change the deduction, which is what one would expect because the constness of the pointer is low-level.

### but with array of const

Nonetheless, if following statements are executed:

```
const int ia[3] = {3, 2, 1};
func(ia);
```

The output is:

```
Deduced type for T is: 4TypeI**A3_i**E
```

So `T` is actually deduced as an array of 3 **non**-const integers. The fact that the argument is a reference-to-const **does change** the deduction, as if the `const` was slipping into the array elements.

Actually, versions of CL up to 18 were deducing `T` as array of 3 const integers was what I expected to be standard, but it seems that since v19 it converged to what GCC and Clang are doing (i.e., deducing as **non**-const).

Thus, I assume the later behaviour to be standard, but was is the rationale ? It could seem surprising that it does not behave like with pointers.

---

**Edit:** Following *dip* comment, I will report here pointers to CWG issues related to this behaviour, pointers he actually posted as a comment on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30866205/1027706) (answer that actually raised this new question... C++ feels like a deep tunnel)

- [CWG 1059](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1059)
- [CWG 1610](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_active.html#1610)
- [CWG 112](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_defects.html#112)

Comment: Top-level qualifiers are discarded from `typeid`.

Comment: @KerrekSB In which context would they be discarded here ? (perhaps you did not see the two first definitions, implementing a trick to keep full type info with `typeid`. Thanks to Alf).

Comment: A reference to an array of const integers is the same type as a reference to a const array of integers.  Let `X=int[3]` and `Y=int const[3]`, then `X const &` is `const int(&)[3]` is `int const(&)[3]` is `Y&`.  The same is not true of pointers.  So this does not seem surprising: the standardese may specify it goes one way or another, but IMHO deducing `const int[3]` for `T` would be a (minor?) defect in the standard (why deduce redundant `const`?)

Comment: @dyp Thank you, the question is edited. I did not post them at first because I imagined you would post them in an answer : )

Comment: @Yakk Interesting ! Perhaps you could publish this as an answer ?

Comment: What's the point of CWG issues with CD status? They have long been included in the WD, and in the last two ISs.

Comment: @AdN because while it is an argument why this behavior is not unexpected, it is not descriptive of what a C++ compiler following the standard should do.

Comment: @AdN: 3.9.3/2: "Any cv-qualifiers applied to an array type affect the array element type, not the array type."

Comment: @KerrekSB "An array type whose elements are
cv-qualified is also considered to have the same cv-qualifications as its elements." (N4296)

Comment: @KerrekSB My point in mentioning those issues was a) that there once has been some discussion about this, and b) the *discussion* of the issues contains information that might provide some inside here. The resolution I think is largely irrelevant here.

Answer (score 1):

Using this function template prototype:

```
template <typename T> void func(const T& a);
```

In your first example, the type deduction works as:

```
const int* ip;

func(ip) => func<const int*>(const (const int*)& a)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^         ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Note: This is pseudocode. The full type is `const int* const&`.

Note that the `const int` remains `const int`, but the `*` becomes `* const`.

This is because `const int*` is just a regular, mutable, non-volatile pointer. It is just a `*`. What it points to is irrelevant.

But in the second example, you have:

```
const int ia[3];

func(ia) => func<int[3]>(const (int[3])& a)
                 ^^^^^^         ^^^^^^
```

Note: This is pseudocode. The real type would be `const int (&a)[3]`.

So the type deduction is working the same in both cases, discarding the outer `const`.

It so happens that a `const` array is the same as an array of `const` elements.

It might help to write types like this:

```
template <typename T> func(T const & a);

int const * ip;

func(ip) => func<int const *>(int const * const & a)

int const ia [3];

func(ia) => func<int [3]>(int const (& a) [3])
```

On that second example, the `const` appears to "move" from being applied on the array to being applied on the elements. This is because you can't really have a `const` array, only an array of `const` elements.

Comment: I was about to comment that `const (int[3])&` is not a C++ type, but you added your note quicker !
Yet I do not understand what you mean by:
"*Note that the `const int` becomes `int`, but the `*` becomes `* const`*". It does not seem like any `const` was discarded in the first example.

Comment: @AdN :) The parentheses I used in both types are also invalid.

Comment: @AdN Sorry, I am not a morning person. Fixed the answer, but it doesn't really change anything. Outer-level `const` is *always* discarded. The problem is C++'s inside-out type system, which means that the `const` in `const int*` is not the outer-level `const`. In fact, the type `const int*` has no CV-qualifiers. It's just a regular, mutable, non-volatile pointer. What it points to is irrelevant.

Comment: The most interesting (part of the) question *to me* is the rationale of the equivalence between the cv-qualifiers >applied to the element type< and >applied to the array type<.

Comment: @dyp It's because arrays aren't real types in C or C++. Sure, you can `typedef` them, but you can't copy them, can't move them, can't return them from functions, and... can't apply CV-qualifiers to them. Arrays exist just barely outside of the type system. C++ tried to fix this a bit by allowing references to "array types".

Comment: You can't copy `void` either, you can't form references to references etc. There are various restrictions on types; so I don't quite understand what you mean with *real type*. Arrays not being copyable has - IIRC - historical reasons; they have evolved from pointers. `const` was added later, via a proposal by *Stroustrup*. -- Since names of arrays are *immutable lvalues*, adding `const` to them doesn't make much sense (but you can add it to an array typedef). The *equivalence* between the cv-qualification of the array and its element types is based on reference binding, according to CWG 112.

Comment: @dyp Maybe saying it wasn't a "real type" was a bit harsh, but you can't deny that arrays are second-class citizens. You can't copy `void` because there simply isn't anything to copy. You can't form references to references because you can't access a reference itself. The rationale for arrays forwarding their CV-qualifiers to the underlying type is so that when you decay `const int[3]` to a pointer, you get `const int*` instead of just `int*`. In other words, it's just historical cruft. This is why we have `std::array` now.

Comment: One alternative to an equivalence between the cv-q on the elements and the cv-q on the array type is to use the same rules as for references types: Ignore the application of top-level cv-q to the array type. E.g. `using A = int[]; using CA = A const;` in C++ is equivalent to `using CA == int const[];`, but it could as well be equivalent to `using CA = int[];` -- So why is it the former, not the latter? I can only guess that e.g. we need to be able to bind array rvalues to references, and those must be `A const&`, so we need some notion of top-level cv-q on array types.